# Change the colour of underline on hover inside a text selection of a custom color in SCSS / CSS?

Tags: css, sass, hover, selection, underline

I have an underline on hover of color (A). I need to change it to another color inside a selection (inside highlighted text).

The problem is that the **underline does not change the colour inside the  highlighted (selected) text**.

Screenshots:

- [1) Here is a screenshot of the highlighted text without hover - this is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NrgG.png)
- [2) Here is a highlighted text with hover - it should show a black underline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4wUF.png)

Does please anyone have an idea **how to make it show underline in the second screenshot styled to black color?**

---

Here's a simplified and edited code example borrowed from @Pawan-Kumar's answer (my original code was confusing):

```css
.link{
  color:blue;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.link:hover{
color:lightblue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: red;
}

.link::selection{
  background-color:lightblue;
   
}
.link:hover::selection{
  background-color:yellow;
  text-decoration-color: black; /* This does not work*/
}
```

```html
<span class='link'>This link</span> should have black underline inside highlighted text.
```

Comment: I think the question could be simplified as follows: Is it possible to style the highlited and non-highlighted underlines to a different color inside one span / div?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following css.

```css
.link{
  color:blue;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.link:hover{
color:lightblue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: red;
}

.link::selection{
  background-color:green;
   
}
.link:hover::selection{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
The color of the lines should be normal
<span class='link'>The color of the lines should be change</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I igured it out: it is not possible...

> Only a few CSS properties can be applied to the ::selection selector: color, background, cursor, and outline

Link to the documentation is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_selection.asp).

Only Firefox [has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection) the `text-decoration` property that can be put into `::selection`.